Подсветка фрагмента кода в Obsidian
Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли как-то реализовать подсветку фрагментов кода (одинарные кавычки) в Obsidian?
Я имею в виду подсветку встроенного кода.
По умолчанию это черный текст на сером фоне, а мне хотелось бы сделать на нем акцент и выделить цветом.

Продемонстрируйте примером, потому что не очень понятно

Решил вопрос добавлением следующего сниппета:
.markdown-rendered code,
.cm-s-obsidian span.cm-inline-code {
    color: #d53984;
}

